# How to start with this

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I want to execute the following command in Python using `for` loops. 
I have written the following code but it is not working.

```
x = 5
for i in x:
    if (x % 2) == 0:
        print (i, "is an even number")
    else:
        print (i, "is an odd number")
```

Why is the above code not working?

I want the results shown below:

```
0 is an even number
1 is an odd number
2 is an even number
3 is an odd number
4 is an even number
```

Comment: -1 if you can't get any code to run at all then just make the code a simple print statement not a  whole program. And you should give more detail re error or output.. that and what DavidPostil said if it's programming related.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
x = 5
for i in range(x):
    if (x % 2) == 0:
        print (i, "is an even number")
    else:
        print (i, "is an odd number")
```

Works fine when I make that change.